# highchart dateTimeLabelFormats don't work

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: container
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 1 // one day
    }
},
xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year 
                 day: '%b %e',  
            },
        },
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}, {
    data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
}]
```

the code upper work good, However when i change pointInterval to 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 7 (1 week), the highchart dateTimeLabelFormat don't work, any help

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"?  Exactly what is the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F2uMR/  the only different is the pointInterview you can find what i say

Comment: It looks fine to me. I don't know what "pointInterview" means. *edit* oh, "pointInterval".  Well it works fine with the 7 day interval.  What do you expect it to look like if not what's showing up now?

Comment: wait a minutes.i will show you the bug

Comment: LOL. I did the exact same thing until I saw Pawel Fus's answer. Also, you should really mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't work because you are setting label format for one day interval, while used is week format, see fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/F2uMR/1/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: '%b %e',
            week: '%b %e'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 7// one week
    }]
});
```